Updating/ Removing recursive child components
I have an application which needs to walk and display a directory structure similar to a filesystem. Below is an example of how this would work with a filesystem.
App.vue
<script setup>
import ListItem from './components/ListItem.vue';

const data = {
  'C:/': {
    'users/': {
      'testUser/': {
        'documents/': {},
      },
    },
    'windows/': {
      'system32': {},
    },
  },
  'E:/': {
    'test/': {},
  },
};
</script>

<template>
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
    <h1>Recursive Directory Browser</h1>
    <ListItem title="Browse" :items="data" />
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped></style>

ListItem.vue
<script setup>
import { defineProps, ref, nextTick } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  items: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
});

const selectedName = ref();
const selectedValue = ref();

async function updateSelected(key, value) {
  selectedName.value = key;
  selectedValue.value = value;
}
</script>

<template>
  <div style="border: 2px solid black; margin: 1em; padding: .25em;">
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
      <template v-for="(value, key) in items">
        <button @click="updateSelected(key, value)">{{ key }}</button>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
  <template v-if="selectedName">
      <ListItem
        :title="selectedName"
        :items="selectedValue"
      />
    </template>

</template>

<style scoped></style>


This code results in an App that looks like this:

The problem is that there is a bug here where a user can walk the directory several levels deep and then if the user navigates back to a different node on a parent directory, the child components for the already explored path remain.

I've solved this by adding a prop/ref called updating on the ListItem component and toggling it between a call to nextTick().
ListItem.vue using prop + component and nextTick()
<script setup>
import { defineProps, ref, nextTick } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  items: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
  updating: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: false,
    default: false,
  },
});

const updating = ref(props.updating);
const selectedName = ref();
const selectedValue = ref();

async function updateSelected(key, value) {
  updating.value = true;
  await nextTick();
  selectedName.value = key;
  selectedValue.value = value;
  updating.value = false;
}
</script>

<template>
  <div style="border: 2px solid black; margin: 1em; padding: .25em;">
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
      <template v-for="(value, key) in items">
        <button @click="updateSelected(key, value)">{{ key }}</button>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
  <template v-if="selectedName && !updating">
      <ListItem
        :title="selectedName"
        :items="selectedValue"
        :updating="updating"
      />
    </template>

</template>

<style scoped></style>


StackBlitz Example
Is there a better solution that does not rely on nextTick() and an added component + prop?

updating flag forces ListItem to be remounted when data for the component hierarchy is reassigned, which is a workaround. The idiomatic way to do this is to use unique key, which is data itself in this case:
<template>
  <div ...>...</div>
  <ListItem
    v-if="selectedName"
    :key="selectedValue"
    :title="selectedName"
    :items="selectedValue"
  />
</template>


Amazing! Such a simple solution. I had known about key in v-for context but didn't know it could be used outside of a for loop. Thanks! Interesting to note that the List Rendering Docs says "The key binding expects primitive values - i.e. strings and numbers. Do not use objects as v-for keys." but this is not mentioned in the key API docs. Do you know if that applies only to list rendering? Your solution does resolve the issue with either selectedName or selecteValue being used as the key.

key is used with v-for because that's where remounting on key change is needed the most. Afaik it's possible to use objects as keys, but I'd expect some problems with ssr. I suppose you can use selectedName instead, it's not unique in general but it's unique on a specific level, which is important
